# Suppress "no mixin named ..." in sass

Tags: import, sass, angular-material, mixins, suppress-warnings

In my scss file use mixin from angular-material:

```
@include input-placeholder-color(red);
```

and I get an error:

```
Error: no mixin named input-placeholder-color
```

but mixin works (i.e. placeholder color is changed).
I cannot use an import to avoid this error:

```
@import "bower_components/angular-material/modules/scss/angular-material";
```

because this changes order of css styles loading and angular-material overwrites my custom styles. The only thing I want to do is to suppress this error because mixin works fine (because it's already loaded in different place).